# pythonでのfor文の高速化（numpyファイル処理）

Tags: python, python3, numpy, 深層学習

pythonにて機械学習用に
「『行列をnumpy形式で保存したファイル（のペア）』を読み出し、行をランダムに入れ替えて、numpy形式で保存する。これを複数ファイル分行う」という処理をしています。

『行列をnumpy形式で保存したファイル（のペア）』の行列サイズは2000万×33と2000万×1で、ファイル数は10です。

こちらの処理を高速化したいのですが、以下コードの中で、改良できそうな点はありますでしょうか？

今まで、https://qiita.com/shaka/items/f180ae4dc945dc7b9066 を参考に、サイズを小規模にして一時変数の利用などは試してみたのですが、早くなったり逆に遅くなったりして、変化が見られませんでした。

少しでも解決できそうな手段をご存じの方がいたら、アドバイス頂けると幸いです。よろしくお願い致します。
コード：

```
# 定義済みの変数
# file_listx： 1種類目のデータが保存されているファイル名のリスト(例：['x1.npy','x2.npy',…,'x10.npy'])
# file_listy： 2種類目のデータが保存されているファイル名のリスト(例：['y1.npy','y2.npy',…,'y10.npy'])

# ディレクトリにあるファイル
# x1.npy, x2.npy, …, x10.npy： それぞれ、サイズ2000万×33の行列
# y1.npy, y2.npy, …, y10.npy： それぞれ、サイズ2000万×1のベクトル

for i in range(len(file_listx)):
    #データの読み込み
    data_x = np.load(file_listx[i]) #ペアのうち1種類目の、i番目のnumpyファイル（行列サイズ：2000万×33）
    data_y = np.load(file_listy[i]) #ペアのうち2種類目の、i番目のnumpyファイル（行列サイズ：2000万×1）

    rand_x = np.zeros_like(data_x)
    rand_y = np.zeros_like(data_y)

    #シャッフル用のインデックス準備
    index = np.arange(data_x.shape[0])
    np.random.shuffle(index)

    #シャッフル
    for j in range(data_x.shape[0]):
        rand_x[j,:] = data_x[index[j],:]
        rand_y[j,:] = data_y[index[j],:]

    #tensorに変換
    rand_x = torch.from_numpy(rand_x).float()
    rand_y = torch.from_numpy(rand_y).float()

    #保存
    np.save(file_listx[i],rand_x)
    np.save(file_listy[i],rand_y)
```

Comment: 1ファイル1プロセス（orスレッド）で並列に処理してみたら、どうですかね？

Comment: 手元の環境(python 3.7.5/numpy 1.18.1/torch 1.4.0)で試してみましたが、実行時間の内、データのロード(np.load)が47%、データのセーブ(np.save)が26%、シャッフルが25%程度を占めています。GPUは利用していませんが、tensorに変換する処理部分は全体の0.5%程度で、disk I/O に時間を取られている状況です(`x1.npy` などのファイルサイズは5GB程度です)。SSD を利用するなどすれば実行時間を短縮できるかもしれません。シャッフルに関しては見直す余地はありそうです。

Comment: [Is there a faster version of numpy.random.shuffle?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26818855) を参考に、`numpy.random.shuffle()` を `rand_x = data_x[np.random.permutation(data_x.shape[0]), :]` の様に書き換えると、実行時間が20%程度は短縮されます。

Comment: Kohei TAMURA様　ご回答ありがとうございます！並列処理は試したことがないので、この機に調べてみたいと思います。

Comment: metropolis様　ご回答ありがとうございます！試して下さったんですね...！本当にありがとうございます。サーバ上で計算しているため、環境を変えるのは難しいかもしれないのですが、検討致します。他の方もシャッフルについて触れてらっしゃるので、見直したいと思います。

Comment: metropolis様　再びのコメントありがとうございます。20%も短縮したんですね。まさかその部分に時間がかかっている（短縮できる）とは思わなかったので、大変参考になります。ありがとうございます。

Comment: 並列処理でどの程度時間を短縮できるか簡単に確認するのであれば、このPythonプログラム内の`for`ループを消して、引数でファイル名を受け取り、10個のターミナルで同時に`python this_program.py x1.npy y1.npy`、`python this_program.py x2.npy y2.npy`、…を実行してみればいいと思います。

Comment: 並列化ではメモリの使用量が問題になるかもしれません。データタイプが float64 だとすると、x1.npy〜x10.npy のファイルサイズは1ファイル当たり5GB程度になりますので、並列処理をする場合は、(余裕を持たせると)60GB 以上のメモリを使用する事になるかと思います。一応、お使いのサーバの搭載メモリ量を確認しておく事をお勧めします。

Comment: Kohei TAMURA様、metropolis様　並列処理に奮闘していたところ日にちが経ってしまいました。ありがとうございます。プログラムに全く自信がないのですが、multiprocessingを試してみたところ、2/3くらいまでに抑えられそうです。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

劇的な効果があるかわかりませんが:

1. グローバルで処理を行わない
2. `np.random.shuffle` を使う

である程度改善しませんか。

```
import numpy as np
import torch


def modify(data):
    np.random.shuffle(data)
    return torch.from_numpy(data).float()


def main(file_listx, file_listy):
    # 定義済みの変数
    file_listx = [f"x{i+1}.npy" for i in range(10)]
    file_listy = [f"y{i+1}.npy" for i in range(10)]

    for path in file_listx + file_listy:
        data = np.load(path)
        np.save(path, modify(data))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: ernix様　ありがとうございます。試してみたところ、0.6%程度削減されました。使わせていただきます。